# AWS roles and policies - limit access to one bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Let's say I have 1k users (not AWS users) and each user have their own S3 bucket. I am going to use signed URL's for them to access their data. For security reasons I want to assume a role when creating the signed URL so that it's limited to their bucket only if they start messing around with the URL.

What would be the best way to do this? Create a role and a policy for each user? Can I create a single role that I attach a policy to when creating the signed URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* create one bucket per user. Buckets are not a scalable resource because there are limits to the number of buckets in an AWS Account.

You could keep all user data in a bucket. If you wish to segregate it by user, use a subdirectory.

An alternate approach is to put all data intermixed, rather than dividing it by user. Your application should maintain a database of each object, together with metadata such as the 'owner', when it was created, any sharing permissions, etc. Then, your app can provide users with access to their data by using [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). This way, your app controls access.

One benefit of this approach is that data can be shared amongst users. For example, let's say you have a photo-sharing app and a user wants to share a photo with another user. The app can maintain a list of what has been shared between users and then create pre-signed URLs to let users access data that was uploaded by a different user. It's the app that determines ownership rather than 'where' a file is placed.

You should not be afraid that a pre-signed URL can give access to other content. A pre-signed URL contains a hashed signature that verifies the object and expiry time. The signature cannot be reverse-engineered and it cannot be used to grant access to other resources. There is no need to use specific IAM Roles that have a subset of permissions.

Comment: Thanks John. Your comment solved a lot of the things that I have been spending a lot of thinking on how to solve but did not write in the OP. I can't stress that enough, really good answer

Comment: I'm trying to do that but I am unable to set an expiration for the URL. When googling it it says that it should be Expires but I'm getting a paramValidation error. presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': 'my_bucket',
            'Key': key,
            'Expires': 3600
        },
    )

Comment: Use `ExpiresIn`. See: [Presigned URLs — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html)